# Connecting transformer with single input and secondary two outputs

Tags: power, pcb, transformer

So I bought a transformer VC16/1/18 and it has two outputs.

I want to get the full output on a single output. Does this look correct?

[image]
[image]

The updated one

[image]

Corrected not

[image]

Final

[image]

Comment: According to the [datasheet](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/700000-724999/710590-da-01-ml-PRINTTRANSFORMATOR_VC_16_1_18_de_en.pdf) the drawing/circuit diagram that applies to any VC 16/1/.. is drawing 1. The left circuit diagram from your question misses the outer pins. You see 4 pins (not 2 outputs) of which 2 pins are connected according drawing 1 of the datasheet. It seems your PCB is correctly connected

Comment: This means I will get the 18V at 888ma?

Comment: What's full? Voltage or current?

Comment: You haven't specified what you mean by "the full output".  The maximum voltage of both secondaries in series, or the maximum current of both secondaries in parallel.  Looking at your "Corrected" layout, you really **don't** want to do that.  It shorts out both secondaries!

Comment: When you use the VC16/ **1** /18 (the one you bought) your **original board layout is correct** and gives a voltage of 18Vac and power of 16VA. If you use the VC16/ **2**/18, the rated output power is 16VA too. Not sure if it is 16VA for each windings or 16VA for both (8VA for each). I think it is the first.

Comment: That you very much for the answer Huisman. Yes you are correct and it was just a problem with the datasheet I think.